# Grouping taskbar icons in Windows 7

Tags: windows, user-interface, taskbar

Look at the screen capture below - note how Windows groups taskbar icons of the same kind (VirtualBox + virtual machine on the left and two Explorer windows on the right). How would you go about doing this for your own application? Are the icons automatically grouped by process, or can you force Windows to group different processes too?

[image: Grouped icons in Windows 7 taskbar]

I've been Googling for this but I'm not quite sure what it is called. All links I've found so far only talk about Windows settings which group / stack / group when full etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a quick Google search, this is what popped up:

> Application User Model IDs (AppUserModelIDs) are used extensively by
>   the taskbar in Windows 7 and later systems to associate processes,
>   files, and windows with a particular application. In some cases, it is
>   sufficient to rely on the internal AppUserModelID assigned to a
>   process by the system. However, an application that owns multiple
>   processes or an application that is running in a host process might
>   need to explicitly identify itself so that it can group its otherwise
>   disparate windows under a single taskbar button and control the
>   contents of that application's Jump List.

Read more about the topic on [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378459(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Thanks, I knew I was using the wrong keywords. That page also answers something else I wondered about, like how some shortcuts don't appear in the MRU and some can't be pinned.

Comment: Just remember to add "dev" or in this case maybe even "msdn" at the end of your query. It helps to filter out non-dev related topics.